# API call timeout using spring web client vs reactor.netty HttpClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, httpclient, spring-webclient

I'm trying to setup timeout on an API call, if response take more than specified time then I need to throw a timeout exception. I'm using spring webclient to make these API calls.
I found two ways to implement it but not able to understand what is the major differences between both the implementations and which one is good in performance, could anyone help me with this ?

Approach 1:

```
webClient.get()
        .uri("/someUri")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(Foo.class)
        .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(10_000));
```

Approach 2:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                .tcpConfiguration(client ->
                        client.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000)
                        .doOnConnected(c -> c
                                .addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(70))
                                .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(80)))
                        .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(100));
         
        ClientHttpConnector conn = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient.wiretap(true));       
 
        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
                .clientConnector(conn)
                .build();
```

Also, could anyone clairfy in approach 2, why we need a "ReadTimeoutHandler" when we have "responeTimeout" ?

Thank you in advance.

I tried both approches but not able to get which approach is idle.

Comment: WebClient should be more efficient as WebClient is built on top of the HttpClient, so I will prefer approach 1 in your use case.